# Will future GUI and CLI releases remain seperate?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, monero-wallet-gui

The GUI beta includes the Monero daemon and other components used in Wolfram Warptangent.

In the future, will the GUI and CLI point releases remain separate or will they be packaged together?

What benefit is there in keeping them separate currently other than to emphasize that the GUI is still in beta status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current intent is to keep them separate for size reasons. The GUI binaries take a lot of space due to the extra libraries needed (Qt, etc), and so there is an advantage to keeping a separate download with just the CLI tools. Those are incldued in the GUI download because (1) it does not add too much space to the Qt/etc size, and (2) they are needed, and so bundling them ensures the GUI gets to use the matching version.